# BinaryReader - reading returns 1 record instead of multiple records

Tags: c#, .net, binaryreader, binarywriter

I am using BinaryWriter to write data to a log file.

However when I use BinaryReader to retrieve the data (within a loop), I am able to read the first 3 writes (integer, integer, byte[]), but the next iteration in the loop to read another 3 just seems to grab the rest of the data (and I cannot process it).

Here's the code:

write code:

```
writer.Write(header.StructID);
writer.Write(data.Length);
writer.Write(data);
```

read code:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
    {
        long bytesRead = 0;
        long readerLen = br.BaseStream.Length;

        //read 1st record
        int id = br.ReadInt32();
        int len = br.ReadInt32();
        byte[] data = br.ReadBytes(len);
        bytesRead += (sizeof(int) * 2) + data.Length;

        while (bytesRead < readerLen)
        {
            //TODO:process data

            //read next
            id = br.ReadInt32();
            len = br.ReadInt32();
            data = br.ReadBytes(len);
            bytesRead += (sizeof(int) * 2) + data.Length;
        }
    }
}
```

Appreciate your help in resolving!

EDIT:

I enclosed the binary write code in a using statement and I allow it to execute only 1 time so I know exactly how many bytes are written.  When I process the read code, the basestream.length is way larger (i.e. I write 80 bytes and the basestream.length shows 1144).

```
    using (writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)))
            {
                long pos = writer.BaseStream.Position;
                writer.Write(header.StructID);
                writer.Write(data.Length);
                writer.Write(data);
                m_LoggingEnabled = false;
            }
```

Here is the binary data:

```
CE 00 00 00 48 00 00 00 AD A2 3B 94 76 08 A7 3E 7A 9A 80 9D CC 1A 2B 3F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F0 BF 91 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F0 3F 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 CE 00 00 00 48 00 00 00 AD A2 3B 94 76 08 A7 3E 7A 9A 80 9D CC 1A 2B 3F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F0 BF 92 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 2A 7A BE 01 00 00 00 50 64 63 3D CE 00 00 00 48 00 00 00 D8 41 B1 19 01 A3 86 BE E2 E2 7A 22 6F 1F 2B 3F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F0 BF 91 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F0 3F 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

I'm really confused now!

Comment: Um, by the time you call `br.ReadBytes(len)` you've read everything into `data`. Where do you expect any other data to come from? Your question is very unclear at the moment.

Comment: Moreso, it looks like you would be better off with a `do.. while` loop.

Comment: Hm, @Jon, how so? If the data were correctly written, how would he read more than len bytes, which hopefully makes up the rest of one record..? (I probably will have to put my foot where it don't belong soon, but, I don't get it..) He seems to simply overwrite data in the loop..

Comment: @Radiohead are you sure? There is no processing code yet - have you stepped through with the debugger..?

Comment: What are the types of header.StructID and data.Length? if they are not integers that could cause an issue when reading.

Comment: Zen - They are integers.  Thank you for your example below.  I will check it out.

Comment: TaW - yes I used the debugger...

Comment: Are you writing in a for/foreach loop?.. can you include the full writing code.

Comment: @TaW: The writer is writing two ints then the data. The reader is reading two ints, then the data (via `ReadBytes`) - *then it tries to read a load more data*. Where is that data meant to come from?

Comment: The writer is not exactly a loop.  It is a timer.  When data is received over the network, I call the write code to add the 3 bits of data to a log.  The writer is declared globally.  To test the reader, I stop the data sending code, then restart the code and go into the reader section where I open the log and read the data.  I can see via a hex editor that data was written to the log.  I do not understand why the basestream length is so much larger than the amount of data written.

Comment: _Where is that data meant to come from?_ from the loop I had assumed. since it isn't there, it is probably some kind of writing/timing/flushing/closing problem..

Comment: _I do not understand why the basestream length is so much larger than the amount of data written._ Neither can we, without the actual writing code..

Comment: That is the problem. When you call again the binarywriter it will write from the beginning of the file, and that causes the reading issues you are seeing.

Comment: Use AppendMode to prevent the issues you are seeing. Check out my updated explanation ;)

Comment: clear the log file before you modify read mode to append, since the existing data in your log is corrupted by your incorrect writes in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `BinaryReader` code is correct, even though you could refactor it to be a little bit less repetitive and more concise.

Based on your limited description i assume you are doing the writing wrong, and not the reading. Make sure that `header.StructID` and `data.Length` are integer types.

Since you are invoking the BinaryReader from a Timer, than you have to be aware that the `Write` operation will write from the beginning of the existing file, since you have not advanced the writing stream to the correct position. That could cause some unwanted behavior (overwriting existing data etc.) and **that is probably causing your reading issues.** You should open your file in `Append` mode to prevent that.

Here is a correct example of writing and reading using BinaryReader and BinaryWriter based on your example. It uses AppendMode on the file to prevent the issues you are seeing (i am reopening the file in a for loop to simulate your timer reopening the file and writing stuff to it):

```
var stuffToWrite = new List<byte[]>()
{
    new byte[72],
        new byte[72],
        new byte[72],
};

for (int i = 0; i < stuffToWrite.Count; i++)
{

    using (var file = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Append))
    using (var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(file))
    {
        binaryWriter.Write(206);
        binaryWriter.Write((stuffToWrite[i].Length));
        binaryWriter.Write(stuffToWrite[i]);
    }
}

using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (var br = new BinaryReader(fs))
{
    do
    {
        int id = br.ReadInt32();
        int len = br.ReadInt32();
        byte[] data = br.ReadBytes(len);

        // Process Data

    } while (br.BaseStream.Position < br.BaseStream.Length);
}
```

Comment: Hi Zen, I am sure I'm doing something wrong but after applying your suggestions above here's what I'm experiencing:

Comment: I watch the basestream.position advancing as I write data.  It advances as expected.  When I read, I can read successfully the first set of data (id, len, data).  Upon the second iteration through the do/while loop, this line returns junk:  int id = br.ReadInt32();  And from that point, all else fails.

Comment: While reading, the basestream.position is moving along as expected.  But when the 2nd iteration through the loop should return an integer, I'm getting the dreaded id = -858993459.

Comment: In the 2nd iteration of do/while loop, at the line id= br.readint32();, the basestream.position is in the expected position to do the readint32.

Comment: I think the problem is that your log file data is corrupted. Have you tried to delete your log file and do a fresh run with a new log file?

Comment: Yes.  I opened the log file and manually deleted all the data; then saved the file.

Comment: Hmm.. maybe you should share exactly the content you are trying to write and the binary output of your file. That way we can troubleshoot whats happening.

Comment: Just cleared out the file with a Hex Editor.  I reran the program and allowed 3 iterations of the "using (writer..." section to run.  I know 240 bytes were written to the log (watching the basestream.position pointer).  I opened the log in the Hex Editor and there were 240 bytes of data.  So I believe the writer code is working as it should (thanks to you for the using statement).  It's the reader code (seems to me at least).

Comment: Well it looks like this: id=206; len=72; data=72 bytes.  The first iteration of the loop returns id=206; len=72; and 72 bytes of data (not yet processed but it's just integers basically).  On the 2nd iteration of the loop, position is at 80 and should be ready to read the next record (which is id=206; len=72; data=72 bytes).

Comment: (BTW:  Thank you so much for your patience with me...)

Comment: Np.. its a fun problem :).. when you open the file with a hex editor you should have three items inside, not one.

Comment: BTW i updated my example with something closer to your scenario. It still works.

Comment: You know...I'm not using your "stuffToWrite".  My 3 write statements are write.int32, write.int32, write.byte[].  Should I convert everything to a byte[]?

Comment: I have tried reading your binary file with my code and i could read it without issues :)

Comment: Weird.  Can you tell me what your reader.basestream.length shows?  In my code, the value is 1144 rather than the expected 240.

Comment: Length on my end is 240. Let me try to run your timer code.

Comment: Hey Zen...found my problem... It was stupid but very misleading!  So I was opening the filestream from path + "log.txt".  I was missing the backslash i.e. "\\log.txt".  I have no idea why I was able to read 1 record with an invalid filename.

Comment: Zen, thank you for sticking this out with me!  You are very patient and kind!  ...and awesome!

Comment: :D at least you figured it out :) no problem ;).. then you can accept the answer if it resolved your issue!

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but since it the accepted answer has helped me to a great extent, I'd also like to understand if this answer and code would also hold good while reading network streams. Specifically, my doubts is about the line " byte[] data = br.ReadBytes(len);" Would this line be enough to correctly read from a network stream (tcp) using BinaryReader? Many thanks in advance.